How can I improve Bluetooth performance with laptop and docking station in a closed cabinet?
I'm having trouble with Bluetooth keyboard/mouse performance while laptop and docking station are in a closed cabinet.
I have a Dell XPS 15 9520, Dell WD22TB4 Thunderbolt 4 Docking Station and a Dell KB7321WI Bluetooth Keyboard and Mouse. The mouse dongle is connected to the USB 3.0 port in the docking station.
The keyboard/mouse keep freezing for at least a minute, every 5-10 minutes. I worked with Dell Support and long story short, after sending me two replacements, we came to the conclusion it was the Bluetooth connectivity that was disrupted by having the docking station in the cabinet. While working with Dell Support, I bought a keyboard/mouse from Amazon. It worked perfectly at first, but soon did the same thing.
Then, I purchased a Techkey adapter in hopes of improving the performance, but it's spotty at best.
Now, I've had to drag my equipment out of the cabinet onto my desktop to avoid the issue. I hope someone has some insight so I can return my equipment to the cabinet and use my keyboard/mouse without the freezing issue.

would extending the bluetooth dongle with a USB extender be an option?  Also cause it might matter - what's the cabinet made of?

@JourneymanGeek, using an extender worked very well for a USB cellular modem I'd used. It also allows for putting the dongle in an open can, i.e., directional cantenna. To make one, just poke a hole in the side of a can for the 2.4 GHz Bluetooth adapter, as shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gK_z9QAsYU4

Perhaps the primary reason your question is attracting close votes is your opening paragraph and the question you ask in it: "has anyone had luck...". This site requires specific questions, and personalizing them and focusing them on your situation and what you need solved is a key way to make your question specific: "I am having trouble with X; how do I solve this?" You don't need to know general suggestions; you want to know how to solve the specific problem you are facing, so present THAT question and your question should remain open, or be reopened if it is closed before you fix it.

I recently solved a similar problem with bad latency/loss for a 2.4GHz non-Bluetooth mouse by using a long USB extension cable to bring the USB receiver closer to the mouse, reducing the wireless distance from 8 to 4 feet.

Sometimes its not a 'technical' solution in an obvious sense.
Select a suitable place you can drill a hole for a panel mount USB header so your bluetooth adaptor is outside your PC. Install it, run a cable to your PC, and plug the bluetooth outside. Its less obtrusive than having your PC inside your cabinet.
If you want a more generic option, a hole saw and a cable grommet would do the same to let your cables out.
I'm not a woodworker - and the details are probably more for DIY.SE, but its reasonably simple if you have the tools.

Here is a [photo] (https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/ubtkf0p2ym64a9tvg0fg2/AKmOKTR2fCimXIGF4fDGhH8?rlkey=xnn3oyln8cohi5fskv6wlnf5j&st=vvbbubmr&dl=0) of my set up. @Ben Hutchinson, are you suggesting connecting and extension to the docking station, then to the TechKey adapter?
